# I want to create bootstrap 4 grid with navbar, sidebar and 2 columns next to sidebar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid

I want to fix my grid, right now its in the middle of page and whitespaces everywhere, what I want to do is sidebar to the side of page no margins, 2 columns next to sidebar in a row with no spaces between them so they together take over whole page which makes 3 columns together with sidebar, and navigation bar above all those 3 columns.

Html Code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                      <div class="container-fluid">

                          <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                              <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                              <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                          </button>
                          <button class="btn btn-dark d-inline-block d-lg-none ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                              <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
                          </button>

                          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                              <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                                  <li class="nav-item active">
                                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="nav-item">
                                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="nav-item">
                                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="nav-item">
                                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                                  </li>
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <nav id="sidebar">
                      <div class="sidebar-header">
                          <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
                      </div>

                      <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                          <p>Dummy Heading</p>
                          <li class="active">
                              <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                              <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                                  <li>
                                      <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                      <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                      <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                                  </li>
                              </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                              <a href="#">About</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                              <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
                              <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                                  <li>
                                      <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                      <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                      <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                                  </li>
                              </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                              <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                              <a href="#">Contact</a>
                          </li>
                      </ul>


                  </nav>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 bg-info">hi</div>
                <div class="col-md-4 bg-dark">hi</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
                $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
            });
        });
    </script>



  </body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
    /*
    DEMO STYLE
*/

@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #ffc107;
    color: #000000;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ffc107;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #000000;
    background: #ffc107;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #e67e22;
}



/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#cont{
  width: 1300px;
}



/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question? What's not working with your code?

Comment: remove gaps between sidebar and two columns

Comment: Can you please include more of your CSS code?  There's nothing for your `<div>` classes ("container", "row", "col-md-4", etc., etc.). which is preventing anyone from assisting you with a valid answer. (thanks)